# Como controlar classes individualmente no jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-toggleclass

Recentemente criei este documento HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="container">
    <a class="button" href="#" title="Abrir as opções."></a>
    <div class="option-box">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Ação 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ação 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ação 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ação 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a class="button" href="#" title="Abrir as opções."></a>
    <div class="option-box">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Ação 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ação 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ação 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ação 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tenho dois blocos `.container`, que já está formatado no CSS, tenho em cada *container* um elemento `a` que adicionará uma classe à div `.option-box`, o problema surge quando clico em apenas um elemento `a` e o jQuery adiciona as classes para o `.option-box` do outro `.container`, fazendo com que apareça dois menus.

#### Javascripts abaixo:

```
$(function optionbox() {
  var box = $('.container .option-box');
  var button = $('.container a.button');
  button.on('click', function optionbox(){
    box.toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

Como fazer com que o jQuery manipule o elemento de apenas um `.container`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai ter que partir do elemento clicado e "procurar" no DOM para encontrar o elemento que quer.

Usando o [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) pode subir no DOM a partir do elemento clicado e depois o [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) para descer para o elemento que quer.

Exemplo:

```
$(function optionbox() {
    var box = $('.container .option-box');
    var button = $('.container a.button');
    button.on('click', function optionbox() {
        $(this).closest('.container').find('.option-box').toggleClass('show');
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cs6erreu/

Como o [@Jader sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37044/como-controlar-classes-individualmente-no-jquery/37045?noredirect=1#comment71263_37045), uma variante mais simples seria somente

```
$(this).siblings('.option-box').toggleClass('show');
```

Isto porque o `<div class="option-box">` é sibling do `.button`.

Outra variante ainda é usar o [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(this).next().toggleClass('show');
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/cs6erreu/1/

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @IsacFadoni juntei mais duas opções. Se o seu HTML fôr como no exemplo elas são até melhores...

Comment: Testei as outras soluções também, e funcionou perfeitamente.Novamente muito obrigado.